# How do I mark current option as selected?

Tags: php, html

I have pages like

```
index.php?key=toplist&list=magic
```

So if om on that page for example, i want the Magic option to be marked as selected in the select menu

```
<select name="skill" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.skill.options[this.form.skill.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="index.php?<?=QUERY_STRING?>&list=experience">Experience&nbsp;</option>
<option value="index.php?<?=QUERY_STRING?>&list=magic">Magic</option>
<option value="index.php?<?=QUERY_STRING?>&list=shielding">Shielding</option>
<option value="index.php?<?=QUERY_STRING?>&list=distance">Distance</option>
<option value="index.php?<?=QUERY_STRING?>&list=fishing">Fishing</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: off: is this going to be a tibia-related site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add the `selected` attribute to the `option` tag. I typically do it with something like this:

```
$lists = array('experience', 'magic', 'shielding', 'distance', 'fishing');
foreach($lists as $list)
    echo "<option value=\"index.php?$QUERY_STRING&list=$list\"" . ($list == $_GET['list'] ? " selected" : "") . ">" . ucfirst($list) . "</option>"
```

Answer (score 3):

For each `<option>` tag, you have to test if the `value` corresponds to the one that is to be considered as selected, and, for the one that is, you have to add the `selected` attribute :

```
<option value="..." selected="selected">blah blah</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the selected attribute. In HTML, this would be:

```
<option value="x" selected>Label</option>
```

And in XHTML, it would be:

```
<option value="x" selected="selected">Label</option>
```

This is an HTML question, not a PHP-question, by the way.